# Java Control Panel won't open

Tags: windows-xp, java

I can't open the Java Control Panel (even with the "javaws -viewer" or "%SystemRoot%\system32\javacpl.cpl" cmds).

I tried reinstalling (after Revo Uninstalling, then after manually deleting all applicable folders [and "Environment variables" PATHEXT = .js; .jse after reading [this external thread](http://www.techsupportforum.com/forums/f217/solved-java-crashes-browsers-and-its-control-panel-wont-open-632405.html); speaking of that thread alas no "program" file in root C:\ to delete]).

Java 7 update 80; Windows XP Pro sp3; Installing Java 8 fails with Error 1603.

I was [living with it even though Firefox occasionally crashed](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1074985) but that became untenable the instant I upgraded to FF42 because my FF42 crashes instantly every time, which is simply unusable.

So I reverted to FF41.0.2 which of course is an insecure solution.

Any advice please?

While I wish I had time to upgrade from XP to a newer version of Windows, I'm disabled and I just don't have the time to do that.  I'm really attached to Firefox, and to Java since I need to use Vuze as my bittorrent client.

Comment: [Error 1603: Java Update did not complete.](https://java.com/en/download/help/error_1603.xml)

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply David.  I already tried the solutions on that webpage and they didn't work.